# list the amount of blocks used by your home directory and everything under it

Tags: linux

What is the command to list the amount of blocks used by your home directory and everything under it? Only one number, not a whole list of them.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
du -s --block-size=$MY_BLOCK_SIZE $HOME
```

Of course, replace `$MY_BLOCK_SIZE` with the block size you want to use, or omit the `--blocksize=$MY_BLOCK_SIZE` argument if you want to use the default of `1024` bytes/block:

```
   Display  values  are  in units of the first available SIZE from --block-size, and the
   DU_BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE and  BLOCKSIZE  environment  variables.   Otherwise,  units
   default to 1024 bytes (or 512 if POSIXLY_CORRECT is set).
```